# How to add .org files under org-directory to agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am facing the following problem: Org mode has the customizable variable `org-agenda-files`. The files listed by absolute path under this variable are used for building the org agenda window. If an element in the list is a directory, then all `.org` files matching the `org-agenda-regex` are processed to build the agenda view. On the other hand there is also another customizable variable: `org-directory`. Shockingly though, if `org-agenda-files` is undefined, the agenda view does not try to use the matching `.org` files under  `org-directory`. Also, listing the paths of the agenda files relative to `org-directory` in `org-agenda-files` is not accepted, as it complains that the files are not found.

My question is, is there an reasonably elegant way to make use of the `org-directory` in the lookup of agenda files, either by using it as the default to look for all .org files, or to describe the agenda files list with relative paths to `org-directory`?

Comment: Just in case, I did notice that the `org-agenda-files` docs say that instead of a list of absolute paths, one single absolute path to a text-file can be added, where the text-file can contain a list of relative paths based on `org-directory` per line, but it sounds like a [PITA](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pita), or "reasonably inelegant" to me.

Comment: `M-x describe-variable RET org-directory RET` provides two (2) express situations when the variable `org-directory` is used -- the doc-string uses the word "only".  The call of the question suggests that the original poster expects or hopes for a more robust usage, however, such a usage was never intended by `org-mode` authors.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually just managed to get it working the way I wanted. So this is how the relevant config code should look like:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-directory "~/Documents/org")
 '(org-agenda-files (list org-directory)))
```

This way the agenda reads from all `.org` files under the `org-directory`, and when `org-directory` changes it follows it. Just what I was looking for ;)

Comment: You can use `C-[` (org-agenda-file-to-front &optional TO-END). To Move/add the current file to the top of the agenda file list. `C-]` will remove the file from org-agenda-file list.